# how to set a network path for filestream filegroup

Tags: sql-server, filestream

How to configure a database so that filestream data is stored on a non local path?

To enable filestream at db level I do first:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase ADD
FILEGROUP FileStreamFileGroup CONTAINS FILESTREAM;
GO
```

Then:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase ADD FILE (
       NAME = MyDatabaseFileStreamFile,
       FILENAME = 'c:\Test')
TO FILEGROUP FileStreamFileGroup ;
GO
```

Now instead of

```
c:\Test
```

I want to set a network path, for example:

```
\\Fileserver\Test
```

but this doesn't work:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase ADD FILE (
       NAME = MyDatabaseFileStreamFile,
       FILENAME = '\\Fileserver\Test') -- THIS IS NOT ACCEPTED
TO FILEGROUP FileStreamFileGroup ;
GO
```

How to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. Although filestream data may be accessed remotely by clients, it must be local with respect to the Sql Server instance hosting it.

Comment: So what should I do if I have huge amounts of data and I want to host it in another machine or in a NAS?

Comment: I believe that qualifies as a separate question

Comment: Yes you are right, I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227499/how-to-manage-huge-amount-of-data-using-filestream-since-only-local-paths-are-sup