# How to manage huge amount of data using filestream since only local paths are supported for data storage?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, storage, filestream

As pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187855/how-to-set-a-network-path-for-filestream-filegroup) when using filestream with sql server 2008 the data must be stored locally.
This means that I cannot use

```
\\FILESERVER\FileStreamData\MyDatabase
```

for Filestream filegroup path.

So if I need to use filesrteam and have lots of data, is buying a very large hard drive the only solution (this could be quite limiting in many scenarios)? It is not possible to use a NAS? Typically one installs SQL Server on a perofrming machine but keeps the large documents in a NAS or anyway on some fileserver. With filestream this is not possible, so how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you can partition your FILESTREAM table to distribute the FILESTREAM data across multiple disks.

Regarding NAS, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695918.aspx#id0400012) article by Bob Beauchemin where he says "Note that the filegroup needs to point to a local file system location; filestreams can't live on a remote server or a network addressable storage (NAS) devices unless the NAS device is presented as a local NFS volume via iSCSI."

It indicates that if the NAS device is presented as a local volume via iSCSI, it can be used to store FILESTREAM data. (I have not tried this though)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also read your blog days ago that helped me a lot with filestream. I will try with what you suggest.